# Could using a Spring Boot version based on an incompatible Servlet API version cause problems?

Tags: java, spring, servlets, spring-boot, compatibility

Spring Boot 1.3.0 and above is based on Servlet API versions 3.1.x. However I am using a standalone application server which is based on Servlet 3.0.x. Could this cause a problem, such as Spring Boot attempting to call a method which was introduced in Servlet API 3.1.x and getting a `NoSuchMethodError` or some other type of `LinkageError` at runtime? Should I be considering downgrading to Spring Boot version 1.1.12, the last version of Spring Boot to be based on Servlet API 3.0.x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Section 9.1](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#_servlet_containers) of the Spring Boot Reference Guide (for Spring Boot 1.4.1.RELEASE) says

```
You can also deploy Spring Boot applications to any Servlet 3.0+ compatible container.
```